# The content of the file when re-accessing the database is incorrect

Tags: java, android, file

Faced such a problem. I wrote data to a file and on the first attempt everything is written well, but subsequent ones output Null. With what it can be connected ?

```
public static String ExportTofile (boolean archive) throws Exception {
        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            throw new Exception("Нет доступа к SDCard");}
        File sdFile;
        File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + GlobalVars.DirectoryPath);
        if (archive) {
            sdFile = new File(sdPath +".txt");
        } else
            sdFile = new File(GlobalVars.AppPathData(), GlobalVars.DirectoryFileName);
        Cursor cDeliveryTable;
        try {
            BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(sdFile),
                    "windows-1251"));
            Log.d(GlobalVars.LOG_TAG, "ExpotToFile: " + sdFile.getAbsolutePath());
            cDeliveryTable = GlobalVars.db.rawQuery("select * from CustDeliveryTable order by _id", null);
            cDeliveryTable.moveToFirst();
            while (!cDeliveryTable.isAfterLast()) {
                CustDeliveryTable st = new CustDeliveryTable(cDeliveryTable.getLong(cDeliveryTable.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                br.write(st.CargoStr() + "\r\n");
                cDeliveryTable.moveToNext();}
            br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;}
        return sdFile.getAbsolutePath();}

public String CargoStr() {
        String sLine;
        sLine = this.Name
                + ";"
                + this.Address
                + ";"
                + this.Number
                + ";";
        return sLine.substring(0, sLine.length() - 1);}
```

First write to file

[image]

Subsequent entries

[image: Файл]

Comment: You do not have to write st.CargoStr() to file. Do away with the file stuff and just Log d that string.

Comment: @blackapps 
This will not solve my problem

Comment: No. But then you know who to blame. I think it has nothing to do with writing to file as you are suggesting. You will better know your problem then.